# formating time difference in dataframe python

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime

I have two rows in my data for which I want the time difference

> ```
>         request           Req_Created       Req_Closed    
>        0 REQ0079455     15/05/2019  16:51   23/05/2019 20:53
>      1 REQ0079455     15/05/2019 16:51    23/05/2019 20:53
> ```

using dataframe:

```
df['Req_time_taken'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Req_Closed'], format ='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M') - pd.to_datetime(df['Req_Created'], format ='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M') 
df.to_csv ("102.csv")
```

The issue is the output is unreadable format

> ```
>           request     Req_Created          Req_Closed         Req_time_taken
>        0  REQ0079455  15/05/2019 16:51    23/05/2019 20:53    8 days 04:02:00.000000000
>        1  REQ0079455  15/05/2019 16:51    23/05/2019 20:53    8 days 04:02:00.000000000
> ```

How do I display the results in the two formats below:

> ```
>           request     Req_Created          Req_Closed         Req_time_taken_1    Req_time_taken_2
>        0  REQ0079455  15/05/2019 16:51    23/05/2019 20:53    8 days 04:02        196 hours 02 minutes
>        1  REQ0079455  15/05/2019 16:51    23/05/2019 20:53    8 days 04:02        196 hours 02 minutes
> ```

Please note the formamting difference in Req_time_taken_1 is and Req_time_taken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `Req_time_taken1`, use `pandas.Series.str.split`:

```
df['Req_time_taken1'] = df['Req_time_taken'].astype(str).str.rsplit(':', 1).str[0]
```

For `Req_time_taken2`, use `pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds`:

```
df['Req_time_taken2'] = df['Req_time_taken'].dt.total_seconds().apply(lambda x: '%s hours %s minutes' % (x//3600, x%3600/60))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
      request        Req_Created        Req_Closed  Req_time_taken  \
0  REQ0079455  15/05/2019  16:51  23/05/2019 20:53 8 days 04:02:00   
1  REQ0079455   15/05/2019 16:51  23/05/2019 20:53 8 days 04:02:00   

  Req_time_taken1          Req_time_taken2  
0    8 days 04:02  196.0 hours 2.0 minutes  
1    8 days 04:02  196.0 hours 2.0 minutes
```

Comment: Is there a way I can display Req_time_taken_1 without the bunch of zero seconds and nanoseconds showing?